# discord.js code doenst store in the database and I dont know the error

Tags: mysql, discord.js

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const userId = message.author.id;
  const username = `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`;
  const xpToAdd = 5;

  try {
    const [rows] = await db.promise().query('SELECT * FROM user_levels WHERE userid = ?', [userId]);

    if (rows.length > 0) {
      const newXp = rows[0].xp + xpToAdd;
      await db.promise().query('UPDATE user_levels SET xp = ?, username = ? WHERE userid = ?', [newXp, username, userId]);
    } else {
      await db.promise().query('INSERT INTO user_levels (userid, username, xp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [userId, username, xpToAdd]);
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('There was an error processing the message:', error);
  }
});
```

So this is my code so im making a level system and it doenst store anyhting i dont know what to do

i was expectinng it to store but it didnt

Comment: Since the code is being ran inside of an async anon function, you can just use `await db.query();` instead of `await db.promise().query()` if you import the mysql2 package as `mysql2/promises`, just a thought.

Comment: What does your console say? There are no errors or messages in your console? Check to make sure the `messageCreate` event listener is even firing--below `if (message.author.bot) return;`, write something like, `console.log(message.author)` and reboot your bot and see what happens in your console when you send a message. If nothing happens, your event listener isn't firing, and could be due to how you're loggin in to your bot.